# Sorting a MatrixCursor in Android

Tags: android, sorting, matrixcursor

I have a `MatrixCursor` like this:

```
final String[] matrix  = { "_id", "name", "price" };
MatrixCursor  data = new MatrixCursor(matrix);
data.addRow(new Object[] { i++, name, price });
```

I have several rows there. I'm looking for a method to sort my `MatrixCursor`:

- according to name alphabetically `AND`
- according to price from the lowest to the highest.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to manually sort all the records first using ArrayList or so.And then you have to add them to MartixCursor.No other way AFAIK.

Comment: But every id, name and price are conected each other. When I'd like to sort names alpabetically each name has specified price. I have to look at one row like a wholeness. What is the best way to manage this task?

Comment: i have no idea for sorting by names but yes,you can sort prices,taking it into an array along with its id.and then you can add them in MartrixCursor.I don't know any other way.sorry!